# Accessing fragment method through activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing a kiosk app where people can walk to and order something.

I have a single activity with bunch of different fragments (order, review, pay, etc). Some replace each other, and some get added. The activity has a single fragment hardcoded `R.id.fragmentContainer` and the rest are programmatically added and tagged.

Now what I want is to have a function in my activity that calls one of the elements of the fragments (look at `updateReceivedData()`) but for some reason I'm not able to do so and I get `cannot resolve method adjustPriceFunc`.

I'm adding the code so someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. The app would normally talk to some hardware so I took out a bunch of those details from the code to make it easier to read.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

List<WeakReference<Fragment>> fragList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.backbone);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new Fragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "SystemDownFragment")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}

public void orderFunc() {
    Log.d(TAG, "orderFunc()");
    if(sendingLogFlag)      attemptSend(TAG + ":orderFunc()");

    for(int i = 0; i < getActiveFragments().size(); i++) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getActiveFragments().get(i)).commit();
    }

    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, "OrderFragment");
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}

public void checkoutFunc() {
    Log.d(TAG, "checkoutFunc()");
    if(sendingLogFlag)      attemptSend(TAG + ":checkoutFunc()");

    for(int i = 0; i < getActiveFragments().size(); i++) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getActiveFragments().get(i)).commit();
    }

    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, "CheckOutFragment");
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}

public void reviewFunc(){
    Log.d(TAG, "reviewFunc()");
    if(sendingLogFlag)      attemptSend(TAG + ":reviewFunc()");

    if(getActiveFragments().size() > 1){
        Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ReviewFragment");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        ft.remove(frag);
        ft.commit();
    }
    else {
        Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, "ReviewFragment");
        ft.commit();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}

public void payFunc(boolean enabled){
    Log.d(TAG, "payFunc()");
    if(sendingLogFlag)      attemptSend(TAG + ":payFunc()");

    if(!enabled){
        Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PayFragment");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        ft.remove(frag);
        ft.commit();
    }
    else {
        Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, "PayFragment");
        ft.commit();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}

public void doneFunc() {
    Log.d(TAG, "doneFunc()");

    for(int i = 0; i < getActiveFragments().size(); i++) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getActiveFragments().get(i)).commit();
    }

    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, "StartupFragment");
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    fragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}

public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for(WeakReference<Fragment> ref : fragList) {
        Fragment f = ref.get();
        if(f != null) {
            if(f.isVisible()) {
                ret.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private void updateReceivedData() {
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PayFragment");
                        frag.adjustPriceFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use method `adjustPriceFunc()` from class `Fragment`, which is not part of it.

Use this code, where `MyFragment` is your proper fragment (I assume it should be `PayFragment`).

```
private void updateReceivedData() {
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PayFragment");
    if (frag instanceof MyFragment) {
        frag.adjustPriceFunc();  
    }                  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is few mistakes here in the code

- In `orderFunc`, `checkoutFunc` etc. add `remove` to the transaction and call `commit` once after the loop, like

  ```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  for(int i = 0; i < getActiveFragments().size(); i++) {
      transaction.remove(getActiveFragments().get(i));
  }
  transaction.commit();
  ```
- You get compilation error in `updateReceivedData` because `Fragment`does not have `adjustPriceFunc()` method. You need either (cleaner approach) create interface with `adjustPriceFunc()` method, let your fragment implement it and then your `updateReceivedData` will look like follows:

  ```
  private void updateReceivedData() {
      InterfaceWithAdjustPriceMethod frag = (InterfaceWithAdjustPriceMethod) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PayFragment");
      frag.adjustPriceFunc();
  }
  ```

Comment: huh, I totally did not catch the earlier mistake. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Storing reference to fragment is a bad practice, even if it is WeakReference. 
Better use this way:

```
   Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
```